# SIP/SIMPLE Client for .net (MSN Messenger)

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a small "Windows Messenger" Client that I can trigger from a script (essentially a notification Bot). It's internal, so I think it uses [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) or [SIMPLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE) against a [Live Communications Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Communications_Server_2005).

Now, before I dig through the RFC's and Wireshark logs, I wonder if there is a .net Library already available that does this? This is for a Server-Side Application, which means that it should work without a GUI and that it should not use unmanaged code.

[dotMSN](http://www.xihsolutions.net/dotmsn/) does not seem to support SIP, and [SIP Objects.NET](http://developers.inova.si/sipobjects/Home/tabid/36/Default.aspx) seems to be aimed only at telephony rather than IM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to roll my own.